# How can I convert an existing word document in to a template with fields that I can update with new information as needed?

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I have some legal documents that already have specific data in them. I want to re-use these documents routinely. Therefore, I want to remove the specific information and replace it with dynamic fields. I imagine this will be some combination of mail-merge / merge fields. The idea is that I can open the file, update the dynamic fields in a single place, then print the new document with the new data.

Considering I am not using a large list of contacts to generate hundreds of documents in a mail merge, but rather I am occasionally opening this document up and I want to simply update those few pieces of information throughout the entire document and print/save.

What is the most straight forward way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like regular mail merge is still perfect solution for you.

- Update Excel data source
- Open template in Word
- Start mail merge with Excel data source
- Preview Results
- Find Recipient
- Additional editing if needed
- Print/Save